# Where do i put the break in my code?

Tags: python, loops, break

```
print'Personal information, journal and more to come'

while True:

    x = raw_input()
    if x =="personal information": 
         print' Edward , Height: 5,10 , EYES: brown , STATE: IL TOWN:  , SS:'
    elif x =="journal":
       print'would you like  you open a journal or create a new one? open or create'
if x =='createfile':
           name_of_file = raw_input("What is the name of the file: ")
           completeName = "C:\\python\\" + name_of_file + ".txt"
           file1 = open(completeName , "w")
           toFile = raw_input("Write what you want into the field")
           file1.write(toFile)
           file1.close()
elif x =='openfile':
       print'what file would you like to open' 
       y = raw_input()
       read = open(y , 'r')
       name = read.readline()
       print (name)
       break
```

every time i try to run the program it keeps on telling me the break is out of loop but i do not know where else i can put the break. also what is a good way to remember where to put breaks at the end of loops?

Comment: Edward, I've looked over some of your previous questions, and I have to ask. Have you worked through any basic python tutorial? You seem to have a lot of trouble with indentation, which is a *very* basic concept in python.

Comment: This is not a bad question.  It's a basic question about very basic misunderstandings, but it's not unclear or inappropriate, so why is it being downvoted?

Comment: i have finished a basic python lesson but i still have alot of trouble with indentation maybe the tutorial was bad do you have a good tutorial on indentation?

Comment: @JasonFruit: Try looking at the style guide here: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/. I recommend get an IDE or something like vim so you can set autoindents.

Comment: Edward, I couldn't find any tutorial specifically about indentation. However, I did find this website which has a lot of very basic examples of good indentation: http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/ifstatements.html. The important thing to understand is that consistency is very important. I would spend some more time writing very small if statements/loops to make sure that you understand how and why they work the way they do.

Comment: If you're using an editor that doesn't do the indentation for you, stop and get a real editor.

Comment: @ChrisHarris: this is not my question.

Comment: I'd recommend you start with very very simple scripts, indenting things... A few *whiles* with *ifs* inside and such... see how things go when you change indentations **:)**

Answer (score 5):

To be blunt: your `break` *is outside of the loop*. You have an if-statement that is not within the while loop.

The way `if x =='createfile':`  is indented, it runs after the while loop runs.

I'm going to guess that you want to reindent your code so that they are all contained within the loop. I also changed the `if` to `elif` since that seems more appropriate here:

```
print 'Personal information, journal and more to come'

while True:

    x = raw_input()
    if x =="personal information": 
         print' Edward , Height: 5,10 , EYES: brown , STATE: IL TOWN:  , SS:'
    elif x =="journal":
         print'would you like  you open a journal or create a new one? open or create'
    elif x =='createfile':
         name_of_file = raw_input("What is the name of the file: ")
         completeName = "C:\\python\\" + name_of_file + ".txt"
         file1 = open(completeName , "w")
         toFile = raw_input("Write what you want into the field")
         file1.write(toFile)
         file1.close()
    elif x =='openfile':
         print'what file would you like to open' 
         y = raw_input()
         read = open(y , 'r')
         name = read.readline()
         print (name)
         break
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `break` statements are part of `if` and `elif` statements that are outside of your loop. Python is whitespace sensitive. You should indent all your `if` and `elif` statements to be inside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation is wrong. Seems like you're trying to break out of the while loop, but your while loop ends at the

```
if x == 'createfile'
```

statement.

You have to fix the indentation of both your if and elif statements so that they are inside the while loop, and then your break statement will work.